# Handling memory in Universal Windows Apps in Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a UWP app for Windows 10. I am having an issue with memory management in my app. I am having a `SplitView` whose Content will have lot of images in it. When the user clicks an image, the full size image will be loaded in the Pane. I am registering to a lot of Click and Tapped events in XAML directly. When I check the memory usage, it keep increasing and after a point, the app crashes. The question I have is, do I need to unregister all the events that I register in XAML for memory to be released? I tried calling `GC.Collect()` but that does not solve the issue. I think there might be a memory leak. There are multiple pages in the app and when user selects Buttons available outside the `SplitView` the Content changes, and how do I unregister the events that are registered in that particular page before making the SplitView Content to have another page.

EDIT:

The XAML for the whole page is more than 300 lines so I can't paste it here. But the events are registered like this

```
<Button Name="Sample" Tapped="Sample_Tapped" Content="Sample Button" />
```

The Page is recreated every time. It is not cached. I have a Frame inside the SplitView Content that is changed everytime the user wishes to change the section of images displayed.

```
MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage),"SampleSection");
```

When the user changes section, I am calling the Garbage collector

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();

    }
```

But no memory is released.

Comment: Needs more info. How do you register for the events? Is the page recreated every time it is visited? Does the leak occur even if the user stays on the page without reloading it?

Comment: I have added more info. Understand that I can't paste the whole code. Its too lengthy. I don't know why garbage collection is not working.

Comment: You know that there are tools named Memory Profilers out there? Use one of them. E.g. Ants Memory Profiler is one of the easiest to use. PerfView is a free Profiler which is the best by the way but it has a high learning curve.

Comment: I am sorry. I haven't used any of them. I am new to development and I don't even know they exist. I'll look it up.

Comment: Does the page itself subscribe to any events? Like a message bus or something? Calling GC.Collect() is pointless, it won't help you, no need to try.

Also I second @AloisKraus's comment. Seems like the issue is not obvious and you will need a memory profiler.

Comment: @AloisKraus I don't think Ants Memory Profiler is compatible with UWP Apps.dotMemory has limited support for UWP Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line causes the problem:

`MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage),"SampleSection");`

You will keep create new Page everytime user select an image. It will eat up memory overtime.

The solution is refresh the Page with new data (new DataContext?), not creating new one. Another solution is to clear the navigation stack of the MainFrame when you need new page using [BackStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.backstack.aspx) property.

Set `NavigationCacheMode` in XAML to 'Required' can help also, but its not the root of the problem.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Correct me if I am wrong, but when creating a new page everytime, the old page memory should be recycled right? its not happening.

Comment: It should not be clear, cause you will need it to go back event if you actually dont.

Comment: The back stack is certainly not endless so it should not result in Out of Memory Exception. Worth the try though maybe the page is heavy.